# remounting read-only GPT filesystem as writable

Tags: mount, permissions, gpt

I'm trying to read from a rescued macbook harddrive - here's the info from `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1   488397167   244198583+  ee  GPT
```

I can read the data from it fine, but trying to write (copying files, etc) throws a permission denied error.  Changing the permissions also gives an error:

```
Error setting permissions: Read-only file system.
```

I tried the solution to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47538/how-to-make-read-only-file-system-writable#):

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,rw '/dev/sdc1'
mount: can't find /dev/sdc1 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, be aware that your problem has nothing to do with GPT, except indirectly (as noted shortly). Also, as Ubuntu's `fdisk` doesn't support GPT, your `fdisk` output is worse than useless -- it's led you to believe that the disk has one partition, whereas it almost certainly has at least two. You should use `parted` or `gdisk` to view the partition table, as in:

```
sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda
sudo parted /dev/sda print
```

Most Mac disks have a FAT32 [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) as the first partition, but this partition is unlikely to hold any data you want. The data you seek is probably on an HFS+ partition numbered 2 or above.

Once you've found and mounted your HFS+ partition, you may run into a permissions issue, because Ubuntu and OS X assign different user ID (UID) values to the first user by default. See the following question and answers for more on this issue:

[How to manage permissions on a shared volume for OSX and ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315078/how-to-manage-permissions-on-a-shared-volume-for-osx-and-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below commands,

```
sudo mkdir /media/os
sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/os
sudo mount -o remount,rw /media/os
```

Your /dev/sdc1 partition will be mounted on /media/os.